# Multivariate KDE Scipy Stats - what if it's not Gaussian?

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density, scipy.stats

I have some 2D data that I am smoothing using:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
kde = gaussian_kde(data)
```

but what if my data isn't Gaussian/tophat/the other options? Mine looks more elliptical before smoothing, so should I really have a different bandwidth in x and then y? The variance in one direction is a lot higher, and also the values of the x axis are higher, so it feels like a simple Gaussian might miss something?

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data. Gaussian Kernel Density Estimation of the Probability Density Function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html is ok for unimodal distributions, as you can read in the docs, bi/multi-modal distributions are oversmoothed.

Comment: PS: if you're not satisfied of `scipy` Gaussian KDE, you can try with `KDEpy` https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html that let you choose different kernel functions

Comment: Data would be something like: `X = np.random.normal(size=(100,1), loc=1, scale = 0.01), Y = np.random.normal(size=(100,1), loc=200, scale =100)` i.e. a much bigger magnitude in Y and a much wider spread, so I wouldn't want a Gaussian KDE, more elliptical?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean exactly, I'll send an answer with your X and Y

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get with your defined `X` and `Y`. Seems good. Were you expecting something different?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate(n):
    # generate data
    np.random.seed(42)
    x = np.random.normal(size=n, loc=1, scale=0.01)
    np.random.seed(1)
    y = np.random.normal(size=n, loc=200, scale=100)
    return x, y

x, y = generate(100)
xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
ymin = y.min()
ymax = y.max()

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax],
          aspect='auto', alpha=.75
         )
ax.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=5)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The distributions of `x` and `y` are Gaussian.
You can verify with `seaborn` too

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
# I pass a DataFrame because passing
# (x,y) alone will be soon deprecated
g = sns.jointplot(data=pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y}), x='x', y='y')
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color="r", zorder=0, levels=6)
```

[image]

---

## update

Kernel Density Estimate of 2-dimensional data is done separately along each axis and then join together.

Let's make an example with the dataset we already used.

As we can see in the `seaborn` jointplot, you have not only the estimated 2d-kde but also *marginal* distributions of `x` and `y` (the histograms).

[image]

So, step by step, let's estimate the density of `x` and `y` and then evaluate the density over a linearspace

```
kde_x = sps.gaussian_kde(x)
kde_x_space = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
kde_x_eval = kde_x.evaluate(kde_x_space)
kde_x_eval /= kde_x_eval.sum()

kde_y = sps.gaussian_kde(y)
kde_y_space = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
kde_y_eval = kde_y.evaluate(kde_y_space)
kde_y_eval /= kde_y_eval.sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax[0].plot(kde_x_space, kde_x_eval, 'k.')
ax[0].set(title='KDE of x')
ax[1].plot(kde_y_space, kde_y_eval, 'k.')
ax[1].set(title='KDE of y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So we now have the marginal distributions of `x` and `y`. These are probability density functions so, the joint-probability of x and y can be seen as the intersection of independent events `x` and `y`, thus we can multiply the estimated probability density of x and y in a 2d-matrix and plot on 3d projection

```
# Grid of x and y
X, Y = np.meshgrid(kde_x_space, kde_y_space)
# Grid of probability density
kX, kY = np.meshgrid(kde_x_eval, kde_y_eval)
# Intersection
Z = kX * kY

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    2, 2, 
    subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"}, 
    figsize=(10, 10))

for i, (elev, anim, title) in enumerate(zip([10, 10, 25, 25], 
                                            [0, -90, 25, -25],
                                            ['y axis', 'x axis', 'view 1', 'view 2']
                                            )):
    # Plot the surface.
    surf = ax.flat[i].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=.75)
    ax.flat[i].scatter(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', c='k')
    ax.flat[i].set(
        xlabel='x', ylabel='y',
        title=title
    )
    ax.flat[i].view_init(elev=elev, azim=anim)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a very simple and naif method but only to have an idea on how it works and why x and y scales don't matter for a 2d-KDE.

Comment: Yes, that does look good thank you, but I'm not sure I understand how! If the KDE puts a Gaussian distribution of width sigma on every data point and then adds them up, if I looked at the x-axis, I'd say sigma was about 0.001 say, but if I looked at the y-axis, I'd say it's about 1. I'm just confused about what approx value of sigma it must be using, as the result does look good, I just wanted to be sure that I didn't need to normalise my data first or something

Comment: You can find here a very good interactive explanation on how KDE works and how different Kernel functions affect the estimate https://mathisonian.github.io/kde/

Comment: @Lizardinablizzard I added an update about the basics of 2d-KDE explaining why x and y scales don't matter